# Capturing console output from proc_open

Tags: php, telnet, proc-open

I'm using proc_open to launch a telnet session connecting to a server program.
Connection is ok but when I get the reply, I can't store the whole string on a file as it is cut after some chars.

Here is my snippet:

```
$descriptorSpec = array( 0 => array( "pipe", "r" ),  
                         1.=> array( "file", $logPath, "w" ) );  
$process = proc_open( "telnet localhost 2323", $descriptorSpec, $pipes );  
fwrite( $pipes[0], "helo" . PHP_EOL );
fwrite( $pipes[0], "quit" . PHP_EOL );
```

I've also tried using netcat and exec:

```
exec( "echo \"helo quit\" | netcat localhost 2323 >> $logPath" );
```

but I had the same result.

If I run the telnet/netcat command from the console, I get the whole string on stdout but if I try to redirect it to another file I get the same prob as above.

Answer (score -1):

```
$smtpConnect = fsockopen($server, 25, $errno, $errstr, 2)){
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect);
$logArray['connection'] = $smtpResponse;
echo $logArray['connection'];
fputs($smtpConnect, "EHLO LOCALHOST". "\n\r");
$smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect);
```

try something along those lines?

Comment: You're not answering the question - *how to write the response to a file*.  Focus on that piece to provide a useful answer.